# Javascript If No Click This JS, Else This

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a slideshow type effect on the homepage of my app, but I am fairly new to JS and am having trouble with some of the intricacies.  I have a working slideshow with delays and setTimeouts that looks like this:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#hero-image-index").fadeOut().empty();
  }, 6000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slide-1").fadeOut(500);
  }, 6000);
  $('#slide-2').delay(6000).fadeIn(3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slide-2").fadeOut(500);
  }, 12000);
  $('#slide-3').delay(12000).fadeIn(3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slide-3").fadeOut(500);
  }, 18000);
  $('#slide-4').delay(18000).fadeIn(3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slide-4").fadeOut(500);
  }, 25000);
  $('#slide-5').delay(25000).fadeIn(3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slide-5").fadeOut(500);
  }, 32000);
  $('#slide-6').delay(32000).fadeIn(3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slide-6").fadeOut(500);
  }, 39000);
  $('#slide-7').delay(39000).fadeIn(3000);
  $('#hero-image-index-2').delay(39000).fadeIn(3000);
</script>
```

However, now the client wants a navigation so the user can go from slide to slide at will, which I have set up using `ionicons` on each "slide".  Here's a sample "slide":

```
  <div class="slide text-center" id="slide-1">
    <h1 style="margin: 75px 0 40px 0; font-size: 52px; color: white; font-weight: bolder">Genetic Golf</h1>
    <h2 style="color: white">We&nbsp;don't&nbsp;guess, we test to find what works best&nbsp;for&nbsp;you!</h2>
      <div class="index-icon-box" style="color: white">
        <i class="icon go-to-7 ion-chevron-left"></i>
        <i class="icon go-to-1 ion-android-radio-button-on"></i>
        <i class="icon go-to-2 ion-android-radio-button-off"></i>
        <i class="icon go-to-3 ion-android-radio-button-off"></i>
        <i class="icon go-to-4 ion-android-radio-button-off"></i>
        <i class="icon go-to-5 ion-android-radio-button-off"></i>
        <i class="icon go-to-6 ion-android-radio-button-off"></i>
        <i class="icon go-to-7 ion-android-radio-button-off"></i>
        <i class="icon go-to-2 ion-chevron-right"></i>
      </div> <!-- index icon box -->
  </div> <!-- slide 1 -->
```

I was hoping to do something with the JS like "if user doesn't click inside `.index-icon-box` then run the js as I already have it, but if they click on an `.icon` then do something like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".go-to-1").click(function(){
      $("#slide-1").show();
      $("#slide-2").hide();
      $("#slide-3").hide();
      $("#slide-4").hide();
      $("#slide-5").hide();
      $("#slide-6").hide();
      $("#slide-7").hide();
    });
    $(".go-to-2").click(function(){
      $("#slide-1").hide();
      $("#slide-2").show();
      $("#slide-3").hide();
      $("#slide-4").hide();
      $("#slide-5").hide();
      $("#slide-6").hide();
      $("#slide-7").hide();
    });
  };
</script>
```

However, any way I attempt this just ends up breaking the part I *do* have working.  Can any js-wizards straighten me out?

Comment: First thing to do is to get rid of all that duplicated code...

Comment: Personally, I would write my "next image" as *one* function that figures out what the next slide should be, and transitions to it - something like `nextSlide()`. I'd put that on a `setInterval()` so that it repeats on a timed interval. The "next" button you want to add can then just call this `nextSlide()` function.

Comment: i recommend using a library like bootstrap that has a component called carousel. why reinvent the wheel

Comment: or slickjs for a carousel. it's pretty decent. and without the overhead of an entire css framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent on doing this yourself without using a library, you might want to try the following.

First consider putting your slides together in a container, and overlaying 
the icons to select the slide over them. Then keep track of the images using the indexes of both the slides and the containers. This provides for an easily edited slideshow setup.

A simple example is shown below, this should be in the neighborhood of what you are looking for.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Hides all images except for one, the one is given by an 
  // index. Also updates the controller.
  function showSlide(index) {
    $('.slides .slide').each(function(i) {
      if (i == index) {
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
      } else {
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
      }
    });
    
    var spans = $('.controller span').removeClass('active');
    spans.eq(index).addClass('active');
  }

  // Show only the first element and set an interval to 
  // continue to cycle through elements.
  var index = 0;
  showSlide(index);

  var intervalFunc = function() {
    index = index >= $('.slides .slide').length ? 0 : index + 1;
    showSlide(index);
  };
  var interval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 6000);

  // Handle clicks which will reset the interval to each time.
  $('.controller span').click(function() {
    // Set the current picture.
    index = $(this).index();
    showSlide(index);
    
    // Reset the interval
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 6000);
  });
});
```

```css
.slideshow-contianer {
  position: relative;
  /* For Deomnstation purposes*/
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2em;
}
.slides img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.controller {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.controller span {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  /* Transition is a personal asthetic. */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.controller span.active,
.controller span:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-contianer">
  <div class="slides">
    <img class="slide" src="https://unsplash.it/400/200?random" />
    <img class="slide" src="https://unsplash.it/400/200?random" />
    <img class="slide" src="https://unsplash.it/400/200?random" />
    <img class="slide" src="https://unsplash.it/400/200?random" />
    <img class="slide" src="https://unsplash.it/400/200?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="controller">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot overstate the wonderfulness of this.  Thank you so much.  I had to add a `delay(400)` to the `fadeIn` because the next slide was appearing below during the transition period, but otherwise this was absolutely perfect!  Thank you again!